# Finding the night differential of two time

Tags: php, time

> I have this two variable:

```
$time_in = 21:00:00;
$time_out = 05:00:00;
```

> I just want to know how I should compute the number of hours of night
>   differential:

*Night differential time are:*

22:00:00 - 06:00:00

> I just want to know if you could suggest anything that can help me for
>   this, if their is a function for this or should I use manually compute
>   it?

Comment: Your time in and out is not the same as your "Night differential time". Is that meant to be? If yes is it always one hour more? What is the expected output?

Comment: i edited my question, I'm sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand properly what you really want to do.

I got this conclusion as I understood

If you use 24-hour time format then specify the date with time, so you can get an actual difference.

```
$time_in = new DateTime('2017-05-18 21:00:00');
$time_out = new DateTime('2017-05-19 05:00:00');
$interval = $time_in->diff($time_out);
echo $interval->format('%H hour(s)');
```

Comment: you just add +1 hour in $time_in and $time_out. Which type of output you really want